# Should all values in a quoted csv file be quoted

Tags: csv

I have a large csv file which I am unable to read into a program during to a problem with delimiter (`,`). When I look inside the file I observe the following.

- I see values such as `"wed, thu, fri"` that contain commas but are enclosed in quotes.
- The quotes are only applied to values that contain commas themselves like the example above or address fields such as `"Cambridge Ave, 115 blah blah blah"`
- The rest of the values (the ones without comma) are not quoted E.g. member ids such as `6754256` or names like `Anders`.

My question is, should all values be enclosed with commas or should I look for the problem elsewhere?

Comment: The answer totally depends on the tool which is consuming the CSV file.  Are you using Excel?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Comment: I've never worked with this tool before, so I can't give you a detailed answer.  But I can say that those quotes are needed to _escape_ the CSV data you have within a given element.  Without quotes, no import tool could make the distinction, so they are very necessary.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know they are necessary. I just don't know whether all other values should also be quoted when one is.

Comment: Again, it depends on the tool.  Some tools allow for optionally quoting column elements, others don't.  What is the source of this CSV data and do you have any control over it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the source is one of our customers but i can edit it so it becomes readable.

Comment: Then edit away.  Those CSV days won't make it intact after the import without escaping with quotes (or something else).